# Firebase Method Swizzling doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swizzling

I'm building an iOS app and using Firebase Cloud Messaging to do remote notifications. I've done nothing to disable swizzling (haven't touched the `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` flag), though the swizzling doesn't appear to be enabled.

The function below is what I've been using to work around the broken swizzling, manually setting the `apnsToken`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    // Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
}
```

When those two lines to manually set the `apnsToken` are commented out, the function below

```
@IBAction func fetchFCMToken(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
    print("apnsToken: \(Messaging.messaging().apnsToken)")
}
```

outputs:

```
***** (the actual FCM token)
nil
```

With the lines setting the `apnsToken` not commented out, `Messaging.messaging().apnsToken` has a non-nil value. This doesn't appear to be the default behavior. Thanks in advance for any help!